# Google Analytics - Profile filter with more than one dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

I have identified some bot traffic in GA, but to filter it accurately I need to filter it by two dimensions, namely Browser and ISP

To be clear, I don't want to apply both a filter to block the entire ISP and the entire Browser segments, but only the combination of the two

To illustrate:

[image: ga profile filter by two dimensions]

Could someone explain how to do this? It's not apparent using the interface and I'm not able to find any documentation about it.

Comment: Just to make it even more clear you want to block a IP based on User Agent?

Comment: Hi, yes almost. Wanting to filter out an **ISP (or "Network Service Provider" or "ISP Domain")**, but only one User Agent, not all

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to build a custom segment. Custom segments allow you to combine criteria.

Or if you really want to filter out this traffic, in your web app pass in a custom page view for users who match this criteria. Then filter based on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in Google Analytics currently.  Google Analytics only allows one field to be used for creating filters.   Neither the "predefined" nor "custom" filters allows multiple fields to be used for a single filter.   Here is a screeshot of the custom filter creation interface.

[image]